# Copy to clipboard button HTML Angular

Tags: angularjs, button, clipboard

Assuming that we have the following

```
<div class="echo" id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
    <pre>
       I want to copy this 
       I want to copy this 
       I want to copy this
    </pre>
</div>
```

And assuming that we have the following button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="showHide()">Submit</button>

<script>
function showHide() {
  document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

How can I create another button to copy the values inside the `<pre>` to clipboard?

And how can I change the label of the "submit" button to "close" and make the div hidden again until you click again to "submit"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ngclipboard](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/ngclipboard/). It's an easy way to implement copy to clipboard.

Include it in your document.

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

Add `ngclipboard` dependency to your module

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngclipboard']);
```

Then simply use it. Here's an example:

```
<!-- Target -->
<input id="foo" value="https://github.com/sachinchoolur/ngclipboard.git">

<!-- Trigger -->
<button class="btn" ngclipboard data-clipboard-target="#foo">
    <img src="assets/clippy.svg" alt="Copy to clipboard">
</button>
```

In you case for example:

```
<div class="echo" id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
    <pre id="toCopy">
         I want to copy this 
         I want to copy this 
         I want to copy this
    </pre>
</div>
<button class="btn" ngclipboard data-clipboard-target="#toCopy" ng-click="submit()">
    {{buttonText}}
</button>
```

In your controller code:

```
$scope.buttonText = "Submit";
$scope.submit = function(){
    if($scope.buttonText === "Submit"){
        document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "block";
        $scope.buttonText = "Cancel";
    }
    else if($scope.buttonText === "Cancel"){
        document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "none";
        $scope.buttonText = "Submit";
    }
}
```

Haven't tested this. But this should work. In both the cases please do let me know.

Comment: Yes you can use ngclipboard. make sure for browser compatibility like in Safari you can not copy to clipboard user need to either ctrl +c or right click copy

Comment: Honestly, i tried it in the following codepen but i might did something wrong cause im in a beginner lvl. 

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZOdWY

In any case thanks a lot for your help!